# How to request scanned image via zxing scanning intent?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I try to make a apps that need barcode scanner,
i already can get the barcode via intent thanks to zxing barcode scanner,
but can i get the image that was capture from the barcode scanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not returned via `Intent`.

Comment: is there anyways to get the image?

Comment: You are probably gonna need a webcam for this. Or, maybe use a barcode writer SDK to decode the barcode value. :)